# Can anyone enlist reasons and ways in which Chiranjeevis acquired long life?

Tags: life-span, chiranjivi

There are few Chiranjeevis who have very long life viz - Parshuram , Aswathama , Kripacharya , Vibhishan.

Why do these people have long life ? Did they get some boon ? While Parshuram is avatar of Vishnu, but how did the rest of Chiranjeevis acquired long life ? What did they do for it ?

Comment: yeah they got boon(s), for example Vibhishan got boon from Lord Brahma (and Lord Rama), Hanuman from Lord Rama (and Lord Brahma, Goddess Sita), Bali from Lord Vishnu (or Vamana), Aswathama from Lord Krishna (this was kind of curse), Markandeya from Lord Shiva etc... it's answered in bits and pieces in multiple posts https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=immortals